# Renaming tag [type-graphql] to [typegraphql]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I think the tag [type-graphql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-graphql) should be renamed to [typegraphql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typegraphql), as the name of the library is TypeGraphQL: https://typegraphql.com/

Comment: Seems reasonable. Done now. With you as soon as caching will allow.